# Baked the duplicate of rigid body object

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I simply create a simple simulation of a monkey (suzanne) falling on top of a grid. Now i just want to make a copy (duplicate) of the monkey and i want to bake the simulation of that copy. So i will then have two monkey with the same exact movement where one is rigid body simulated and the other is keyframed (baked).

The problem is : since they're occupied the same location in space, they will interact each other , so give me the wrong movement. How can i temporarily disable the original monkey so i can then bake the simulation of the copy properly ?

Comment: Make Suzanne a rigid body, bake it to keys, duplicate it (Suzanne.001). Make Suzanne *not* a rigid body, simulate Suzanne.001 as you wish. Would this work?

Comment: If i bake it before i duplicate it, i will lose the previous good simulation. right ? i'm in the process where : i'm making simulation , duplicate it , bake the copy , render the copy. if client want to modify, i go back to original one, edit it , duplicate again (delete previous copy first), bake the copy , re-render. This process will cycle couple of times as the client wants to modify it. I don't want render the original one because sometime i got glitch when render it so i prefer render the baked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collision groups (or Collisions/Collections in 2.80) in the physics panel. If you set the Suzanne copy to collision group 2 and set the grid to groups 1 &2, then both Suzannes will interact with the grid but not with each other.